# SQL Select row with max value in one column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query

```
SELECT Dnumber, SUM(WORKS_ON.Hours) AS sum_hours 
FROM DEPARTMENT 
JOIN PROJECT ON DEPARTMENT.Dnumber = PROJECT.Dnum 
JOIN WORKS_ON ON PROJECT.Pnumber = WORKS_ON.Pno 
GROUP BY Dnumber
```

RESULT:

```
Dnumber   sum_hours
--------------------
1           25.0
4          115.0
5          150.0
```

I want to select the row with the MAX `sum_hours`. I tried using

```
SELECT s.Dnumber, MAX(s.sum_hours)
FROM 
    (SELECT Dnumber, SUM(WORKS_ON.Hours) sum_hours 
     FROM DEPARTMENT 
     JOIN PROJECT ON DEPARTMENT.Dnumber = PROJECT.Dnum 
     JOIN WORKS_ON ON PROJECT.Pnumber = WORKS_ON.Pno 
     GROUP BY Dnumber) s 
GROUP BY s.Dnumber
```

But this returns the exact same result (all three rows).

Any idea how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
SELECT TOP 1 Dnumber, SUM(WORKS_ON.Hours) sum_hours 
FROM DEPARTMENT 
JOIN PROJECT ON DEPARTMENT.Dnumber = PROJECT.Dnum 
JOIN WORKS_ON ON PROJECT.Pnumber = WORKS_ON.Pno GROUP BY Dnumber
ORDER BY SUM(WORKS_ON.Hours) DESC
```

Comment: what if I wanted to add another column (Pno for example) to the result. Is there a way to achieve that with the same query?